# factory_girl + carrierwave + fixture_file_upload -> path being nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, carrierwave, factory-bot

I'm using [`fixture_file_upload`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/TestProcess/fixture_file_upload) in my factory in the field that is mounted using carrierwave. So, I have the following:

model:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::base
  mount_uploader :translated_xliff, XliffUploader
end
```

factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job do
    translated_xliff { fixture_file_upload(
                           Rails.root.join(*%w[spec fixtures text.xliff])) }
   end
end
```

That worked fine, but now I'm adding an action on my Job controller that let a person to download this file. For this, I have the following action:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def xliff
    job = Job.find(params[:id])
    send_file(job.translated_xliff.path, disposition: 'attachment')
  end
end
```

But this raises an exception on the `send_file` line:

```
Exception: no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

Using `byebug` I found out that both `path` and `file` are `nil`, so I suppose the factory girl is failing in add the file.

I'm using rails 3.2 and ruby 2.0. What am I doing wrong? Should I mock the path method, or upload the file a different way?

Comment: Can you share the stack trace for your exception?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin sorry for the delay with this, I was not able to access the code again until this moment. Here is the [full stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/eStBbNPs) note that the example I gave is not my actual full code, is a simplification of how the problem happens. As I told, stopping with the debugger in the controller, I can see clearly that the path for `translated_xliff` is `nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the file name is wrong, it is not `text`, it is `test`. I'm not sure why, but factory girl didn't throw an error as usually does, but this is out of escope for my question.

Comment: Ha, if I had a dollar for everytime I did that

Comment: @marflar and obvious I could never spot this all by myself - not even after an year.

Answer (score 1):

Does it help if you use the following:

```
job.translated_xliff.file.path
```

If that fails, what happens when you use Rack::Test:UploadedFile.new in your factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job do
    translated_xliff { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.open(Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'text.xliff')), 'application/x-xliff+xml') }
  end
end
```

Comment: `Exception: undefined method 'path' for nil:NilClass`, so it seems file is not defined also. The same happens using `UploadFile` from `Rack`, and simply using `File.open` - both `.file` and `.path` are nil

Comment: Oh, forget it. The file name is wrong, and there was no error throw on factory girl side.